# Lightmapped prefabs for procedural content

Tags: unity, lighting, procedural, lightmap

I'm doing a game with procedural content from handmade prefabs, but I ran into a problem as Unity bakes the *scene* instead of *objects* when lightmapping with Beast. So when the prefabs are instanced they are without lightmaps.

Is there a way to get lightmaps for dynamically created prefabs with Unity's built-in lightmapper?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [Lightmap Manager 2](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/94813-Lightmap-Manager-2-Animated-Lightmaps-per-object-baking-and-saving)

Also, a recent update to Unity (sorry, can't remember if it was 4.1 or 4.2) exposed some additional lightmapping methods in the API which help with this.